# Is there a list of giveaway sets from Toys R Us or other events?

Tags: shopping

Toys R Us frequently has giveaway sets called "Make and Take", where kids are invited to come in, build a set and then take it home for free. This is similar to the Lego Brand Retail store Monthly Mini Model Build events. The MMMB kits are typically very similar to Lego polybag sets: they come in plastic bags, they have a set number, they have high-quality instructions. (Some months one of those things might not be true, but in general all three are true). The MaT kits, however, seem to be a little more ad-hoc, but at the end you still end up with a build that has a full instruction sheet and a decent handful of parts.

An example of a MMMB set is [40127, a space shuttle.](http://rebrickable.com/sets/40127-1/monthly-mini-model-build-february-2015-space-shuttle-monthly-mini-model-build-2015), which was February 2015's MMMB.

An example of a MaT is [Emmet's Car](http://rebrickable.com/sets/EMMETSCAR-1/emmet039%3Bs-car-the-lego-movie-2014) which was available at Toys R Us at different times depending on your country (the events are not coordinated like the Lego Store events are).

As you may surmise from my use of Rebrickable links, I like to keep a detailed list of all the kits I and my kids own. However, Emmet's car is the only example of a MaT kit I've found. Is there a detailed list of the kits that have been given away, with instructions, inventory, etc?

I'm primarily interested in finding the MaT kits on Rebrickable, but if they're not there I'll accept info from other sources. I'm mostly interested in MaT kits given away at Toys R Us in Canada, but for other people's benefit would like to know about kits like this from other retailers, or in other countries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Brickset.com](https://brickset.com/) (I'm the founder of the site). We list all that we are told about.

You can also record your collection there, and keep it in sync at [Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/).

Comment: Is there an easy way to find the make-and-take kits there?

Answer (score 0):

Since I started working there (this past year) on the days I was there we had a sponge Bob one and LEGO Ninjago. If you're interested in getting future ones let me know and I'll grab a few for you. At the end of the event we usually have at least a box full that they put in the break room for employees to take.